# Page Up and Page Down as entries in jumplist in (Neo)Vim

Tags: vim, neovim, jump-list

Sometimes I move vertically using {} [] operations in (Neo)Vim, and such operations go fine with jumplist so I can navigate the history of cursor movements using control-i control-o.

However, Page Up and Page Down are not considered as "jump operations", so they are not recorded in the jumplist.

Is there any established solution to add Page Up and Page Down in the jumplist?  Or something that records every position of the cursor?

Comment: `<PageUp>` and `<PageDown>` are not "jump commands" because they are supposed to be used for scrolling, not for moving the cursor. In general, it is best to avoid relying on "happy side-effects".

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/31197/18609 and you could adapt that to (also) handle PgUp and PgDown. Btw check out [vi.se] for questions on Vim!